# Как откатить изменения в картинке?

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage

Цель: создать редактор изображений, который будет накладывать на картинку эффекты, выводить результат на экран, кроме того: возможность откатить изменения. Вроде все прозрачно, но почему-то кнопка отката не работает вообще, а изображение принимает последовательно все фильтры. И если второе "не баг, а фича" то вот отсутствие функции возвращения к первоначальному изображению, определенно недостаток программы.

```
this.workFile = file;
resultImg = reader(workFile);
baseImg = resultImg;
origin = painterLabel(resultImg);
bBack = newButton("Back", new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    origin = painterLabel(baseImg);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
```

Добавление файла, картинки и кнопки.

```
private BufferedImage reader(File file){
    BufferedImage img = null;
    try{
        img = ImageIO.read(file);
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return img;
}

private JLabel painterLabel(BufferedImage i){
    JLabel l = new JLabel();
    l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(i));
    return l;
}
```

Методы чтения, добавления.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без **явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Как и где вы изменяете изображение? Конкретно в вашем примере `baseImg` и `resultImg` ссылаются на одно и то же изображение. И что за функция `repaint`? Вы прикрепили лишь какой-то кусочек кода, по которому сложно понять общую картину

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, у вас создается не копия объекта вот здесь:

```
baseImg = resultImg;
```

а ссылка на объект, после чего baseImg становится псевдонимом для resultImg, и в памяти не сохраняется предыдущее состояние, к которому вы хотите откатиться.